# Random Walk Metropolis: acceptance probability with truncated normal proposal

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I want to draw from my target density $p(\theta)$ using Random Walk Metropolis.

$\theta$ has domain $[2, +\infty)$, and I am using as proposal a truncated normal, namely:

$$q(\theta_t') \sim N(\theta_{t-1}, \sigma^2)_{[2, \infty)},$$

where $t$ is the number of iterations. The acceptance probability will be given by:

$$r = \frac{p(\theta'_t)\,q(\theta_{t-1}|\theta'_t)}{p(\theta_{t-1})\,q(\theta'_t|\theta_{t-1})}$$

How can I calculate  $$\frac{q(\theta_{t-1}|\theta'_t)}{q(\theta'_t|\theta_{t-1})}?$$

Comment: a trick you can to is to re-parametrize. Let $\theta = e^{-\omega} + 2$, and sample $\omega$ from a non truncated normal. Then $(-\infty, \infty)$ is mapped to $[2, \infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a truncated Normal distribution proposal means that it is no longer a random walk Metropolis proposal: the density of $\theta^\prime_t$ given $\theta_{t-1}$
$$q(\theta^\prime|\theta)=\sigma^{-1}\varphi([\theta^\prime-\theta]/\sigma)\mathbb I_{(2,\infty)}(\theta^\prime)\big/\Phi([\theta-2]/\sigma)$$
differs from the density of $\theta^\prime_t$ given $\theta_{t-1}$
$$q(\theta|\theta^\prime)=\sigma^{-1}\varphi([\theta-\theta^\prime]/\sigma)\mathbb I_{(2,\infty)}(\theta)\big/\Phi([\theta^\prime-2]/\sigma)$$
and the ratio of the proposals thus differs from one (1).
[This is not an issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/345650/7224), apart from the terminology.

Note that [another valid proposal](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/bounded-target-support/) is to use the untruncated Normal distribution
$$q(\theta^\prime|\theta)=\sigma^{-1}\varphi([\theta^\prime-\theta]/\sigma)$$
and to reject any proposal $\theta^\prime$ less than two (2), replicating the current $\theta$ instead. In this case, the proposal is symmetric and qualifies as a random walk proposal.

Comment: How did you derive the expressions for $q(\theta|\theta')$ and $q(\theta'|\theta)$? Maybe is simple but I am asking exactly that.

Comment: A truncated Normal is a Normal density restricted to a subset like $[2,\infty)$ hence requiring renormalising to integrate to one over that very subset.

Comment: Could you please show it or at least give me a reference on this. Why do I get the ratio of a pdf and a cdf? Thanks

Comment: It is not the ratio of a density and of a cdf, rather the ratio of a density in $\theta^\prime$ and of a constant that happens to depend on $\theta$. Integrate in $\theta^\prime$ to show it has a mass equal to $1$..