# Interpreting posterior with Half-Normal shape

Tags: bayesian, pymc

I am building a Marketing Mix Model in PyMC and am not sure how to interpret the posteriors, especially those with half-normal priors (sigma=1). I’ve chosen this prior because media could not have a negative effect on the revenue. After sampling, the posteriors for some beta’s look like this:

[image]

Is there a non-zero effect here at all? and how can I test this? Furthermore, I am curious how to determine the effect size. I feel that the mean and median are positively biased here, as the the posterior cannot take on negative values.

All variables are 0-1 transformed.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you described your model. What is response? What are the predictors and what is the likelihood P(data|model pameters)? What is the x axis in the figure above. We know what the y axis is.

I'll take a wild stab: $y = \beta_0 +\beta_1 x$, where $x$ is number of online impressions, $\beta_1$ posterior is what you are sampling and $y$ is . . . sales volume? And your likelihood is Gaussian $N(y-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x), \sigma^2)$. Your prior is $\pi(\beta_1) = N_+(\beta_1,\sigma_{\beta_1}^2 )$.

Regardless of the accuracy of my guesses, your graph means that the probability that Pr$(\beta_1< 0.1) \approx 0.9.$

> Is there a non-zero effect here at all?

Likewise, I'd guess that Pr$(\beta_1>0.05) \approx 0.9$. So yes, there's a nonzero effect, as long as $\beta_1 = 0.05$ is somehow noteworthy.

> and how can I test this?

Do you mean to test the quality of the MCMC? The Gelman-Rubin diagnostic test will determine if your MCMC chains have converged. Assuming they have, what other test would you like to do? Most empirical questions can now be answered by appealing directly to the posterior sampling. Interpretation of the posterior is as easy as integrating it. My guesses aren't true integrations, but if you simply count the fraction of samples in the domain of interest, you can obtain an arbitrarily good numerical estimates of credibility intervals, etc.

> Furthermore, I am curious how to determine the effect size.

Effect size is associated with statistical power, which requires both a null and an alternative hypothesis. Once you have selected these, you will re-do the simulation I'll be your null $\mathbb{H}_0: \beta=0$? But what is $\mathbb{H}_a$? What is a meaningful difference from zero?

> I feel that the mean and median are positively biased here, as the the posterior cannot take on negative values.

Do you mean to say that you think you are overestimating the true mean and true median? That would cause a positive bias. Positive estimates by themselves do not constitute a positive bias.

This "answer" goes as far as your description of the problem goes. I can provide more answer if you provide more story.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your reply. I do think I am overestimating the true mean and true median. One of the reasons why I think that is because I created a new variable with random data (sampled from a normal distribution) which I added to the model. For the beta, I used a HalfNormal prior aswel (with sd=1). After sampling, the posterior has the same shape as the one posted (but then with a slightly smaller mean/median). If I scale back this variable and calculate the contribution based on the mean/median, the impact is almost similar to that of some of the media variables.

Comment: Regarding the model:
my dependent variable is daily sales (0-1 scaled) with a Student-T likelihood with nu = pm.Gamma(name="nu", alpha=25, beta=2) and sigma = pm.Exponential('sigma', 10). The rest of the model is almost the model setup is almost the same as the model in this post: https://juanitorduz.github.io/pymc_mmm/