# Is there a way to restrict the relationship of parameters in MCMC?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have seen some discussion on the restriction on the parameter space such as [MCMC on a bounded parameter space?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73885/mcmc-on-a-bounded-parameter-space) this post, but I am wondering if there is a method to restrict the function or relationship of parameters in MCMC. So For example, I am fitting a linear mixed model where $\sigma^2$ is a variance for the random effect and $\tau^2$ is a variance for the random error. What if I want the ratio $\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \tau^2}$ to be less than some number p? I've been trying to find this method on Google Scholar but haven't had success finding any article. I used keywords: restricted mcmc, constrained mcmc. Can anyone tell me what keywords I can use to find this approach anywhere or direct me to an article that did something similar to this?

Comment: Are you doing metropolis within gibbs? If so, the easiest way, if not the most efficient one, is simply to sample $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$ as usual, but in each case, if $\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2} > p$, count this as a rejection in the accept-reject step and move on to the next parameter.

Comment: You may find some useful advice here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73885/mcmc-on-a-bounded-parameter-space?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The question is a bit vague, as the restriction may as well induce a reduction in dimension, for instance if one picks an equation such as $\sigma^2+10\tau^2=1$ for one's restriction. In this case, there are measure theoretic issues that are far from trivial and only slowly uncovered, See e.g. https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/84/4/1229/7073285 or http://www.lukebornn.com/papers/bornn_jrssb_2019.pdf

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks for the suggestion -- I was hoping to find a little more efficient way of doing it, but what you suggest might be the way to go for me.

Comment: @jbowman I actually read the post and thought I could find something different but it might not be that much different.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for the links! I will take a look